# Merge pop pst into exchange pst file remotely

Tags: outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010, pst

I have a pst file I want to upload to an exchange server and be made a permanent part of the exchange mailbox.

Can this be accomplished by going into file->advanced->export->"import from another program" and importing the pst file?

I need to make sure the merged emails get stored on the exchange server because this isn't my mailbox and I was planning on setting up a new mail profile on my computer to do the import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified this process will in fact merge an imported pst into the exchange mailbox on the server.

File -> Advanced -> Export -> "Import From Another Program"

Outlook will import the pst then click synchronize and the added emails will be pushed back up to the exchange server.